# Is it possible to create a wrapper directive that can be reused with different content?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create a wrapper directive that can be reused with different content?

The template myWrapper.directive.html only contains the following:

```
<div aria-hidden="{{isDialogOpen}}"></div>
```

I want to use my wrapper like this:

```
<my-wrapper>
 <content1 />
</my-wrapper>

<my-wrapper>
 <content2 />
</my-wrapper>
```

I what content1 and content2 to be inserted inside of the div in myWrapper.directive.html.

Comment: start with reading this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude if u have some concrete questions u r welcome back

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Why didn't you provide this as an answer? @PetrAveryanov